# DOCUMENT_ROOT set but can't get it in script. Why?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, ini

I have php scripts that were working ok since Ocober last year, last I remember was 2 months ago and today while executing them I have problems with _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable.

If I look at the _SERVER array, it is not set. While if I execute in a script:

```
phpinfo();
```

Then the variable is there and set.  But calling it:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Returns null

What is the reason for this? How can I use it again in my scripts? I figure the cause was a php or apache update, but both have been updated few times in the last 2 months.

Also, I don't see DOCUMENT_ROOT in php.ini file. I do see doc_root, which is different.

My php:
    PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7
apache: 
    PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.7

Comment: As I wrote, that contains an empty string in DOCUMENT_ROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is an environment variable normally set by the (apache) webserver before calling you script via CGI. If your webserver has a bug or is misconfigured, it can happen that this environment variable is not set any longer.

You can try to debug and/or hotfix that with mod-rewrite, mod-cgi, mod-setenv or similar. If that is all above your head, please contact your server administrator and discuss the issue because it can have many reasons.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the var was empty because I was calling the script from terminal - thus skipping apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `print_r($_SERVER)` , and see if it's really set

Comment: are you calling the script from the command line ? instead of regular call from a browser ?

Comment: Yes, and that was it, thanks :). Tried with browser and that works
Then I guess like Hakre said, this var comes from apache thus since calling in terminal skips that, var is then empty.

Answer (score 0):

If may be an Apache configuration issue : did you define a document root in your Apache configuration file ?

Otherwise, you can bypass it by using :

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

or :

```
substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```